# Why does this access list block DHCP request?

Tags: vlan, packet-tracer, access-control

To prevent IP spoofing in a VLAN I configured the following access list

```
 ip access-list extended MITARBEITER
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit udp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit icmp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any


 interface GigabitEthernet0/1.240
 encapsulation dot1Q 240
 ip address 10.15.240.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MITARBEITER in
 ip nat inside
 standby 240 ip 10.15.240.1
 standby 240 priority 150
 standby 240 preempt
```

I tested it and when I remove ip access-group MITARBEITER in the DHCP request are not blocked by the router. (Using Packet Tracer). What is the problem?

Comment: You are only permitting traffic from that one `/24` network into the router through that interface. You can simplify it by using `ip` on one line instead of the three different lines of `tcp`, `udp`, and `icmp`.

Comment: But by using IP I would block protocols below L3 in the OSI model like. ARP, STP, CDP?

Comment: STP, CDP, etc. are link-only protocols that do not leave the interface on which they are received. ARP does not cross routers. You are no more blocking them with `ip` than you are by choosing only higher-layer protocols like TCP and UDP.

Comment: It's an ***IP*** access-list, so it will only apply to IPv4 layer-3 traffic. ARP, STP, and CDP aren't IP.

Comment: Moreover, an IP(v4) ACL doesn't block IPv6 or other L3/L2 traffic...

Answer (score 4):

DHCP Discover broadcast has to be whitelisted explicitly

```
    ip access-list extended MITARBEITER
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 permit TCP 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit UDP 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit icmp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

The list can be simplified to

```
ip access-list extended MITARBEITER
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 permit IP 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

Now it works!

Comment: You are still using three lines where one would work.